# How to read a text file, then capture and read new added line

Tags: matlab, octave

I have a script in octave, I want the script to go over a text file and print each line of the file. I want the script to run in an endless loop and each time the file gets a new line to print it. I tried doing this using this code:

```
arg_list = argv ();
file_name = arg_list{1};
if (!(exist(file_name,"file")))
    error (["file ",file_name," doesn't exist."]);
end;

fid = fopen(file_name,"r");

while (1)
    s=fgetl(fid);
    if (ischar(s))
        disp(s);
    end;
    usleep (1e5);
endwhile;
```

The problem is when the script reaches the end of the file, it'll get stack on it, even if new lines are added to the file. If new lines are added to the file **Before** the script reaches the end, then it'll see them and print them.

Is there a way for octave to see new lines added to the file, after it reaches EOF?

This runs under Linux.

<sup>* - The final script will do evaluations on the lines, and not just print them. The print is only a way to test the mechanism.</sup>

Comment: Are you doing that on a Windows system or Linux ? Also how often are lines likely to be added to the file (few per seconds or few per minutes etc ...)

Comment: @Hoki. linux, and few per minute. The lines will be added by a user interactively (by hand), so no faster than human typing speed.

Comment: May I suggest modifying the title of your question. The current title describe what doesn't work in your current implementation, but is not so descriptive of your actual question at the end of your post: "_Is there a way for octave to see new lines added to the file, after it reaches EOF?_".

Comment: @Hoki, feel free to edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by setting up a timer and a callback function called at regular intervals. The callback will check the file for new lines and do the processing on them if relevant.

First save the following function as `return_new_lines.m` somewhere in your matlab path. This function is the one that check the file for new lines. It returns an empty cell array if no new lines are found in the file, and a cell array of string lines if it finds new one.

```
function newLines = return_new_lines( file2watch )

%// initialise and preallocate
persistent oldFileSize
if isempty(oldFileSize) ; oldFileSize=0 ; end
newLines = {} ;

fid = fopen( file2watch , 'r' ) ;

%// Get size of the file
fseek( fid , 0 , 'eof' ) ; %// place cursor at the end of the file
newFileSize = ftell( fid) ; %// get position of cursor

bytes2read = newFileSize - oldFileSize ; 
if bytes2read
   oldFileSize = newFileSize ;
   %// read the new lines
   fseek( fid , -bytes2read , 'eof' ) ; %// place cursor at the beginning of the new part of the file
   iLine = 1 ;
   while ~feof( fid )
      newLines{iLine,1} = fgetl( fid ) ;
      iLine = iLine+1 ;
   end
end

fclose( fid ) ;
```

---

Next, this function `processNewLines.m` will be called by the timer callback:

```
function processNewLines(obj,evt, file2watch ) %#ok<INUSL>

newLines = return_new_lines( file2watch ) ;

if ~isempty(newLines)
   disp(newLines)
   %// ...
   %// do your processing on these new lines
   %// ...
end
```

---

Then in your workspace or in your gui, define:

```
file2watch = 'L:\TEMP\MatlabCode\StackExchange\test.txt' ; %// change that to your filename
fileUpdater                = timer ;
fileUpdater.Period         = 5 ; %// set to 5 seconds, adjust that to your needs
fileUpdater.TimerFcn       = { @processNewLines , file2watch } ;
fileUpdater.ExecutionMode  = 'fixedRate' ;
```

To start the process, execute:

```
start( fileUpdater )
```

And when you are done (nobody is adding lines to your files), stop the timer with:

```
stop( fileUpdater )
```

---

The first time you will start the timer it will read all the lines of the file. Then it will periodically check for added lines. If you open your text file, add a new line and save the text file, you should see it shortly popup in the command window.
(*Remove the call to `disp` when you are done testing.*)

---

Note: The functions `return_new_lines` could be embedded into `processNewLines` instead of separate functions if you want to limit the number of `.m` files. I did it this way just because the function that check for new lines in a file could be reused in other cases, so I kept it separate.

---

**edit:**
I almost forgot. The `persistent oldFileSize` declaration in the function `return_new_lines` is what make the variable remember how many lines were read on previous executions of the function. Thanks to that only new lines will be returned by the function.
If you want to ***reset*** the function and read again from the beginning of your text file, you have to `clear` the function in which the persistent variable is declared. So doing:

```
clear return_new_lines
```

will make your function read the file from the beginning again.